# Unexpected value 'Validators' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am using angular reactive forms in my application.

Below is my app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        SignupComponent,
        PagenotfoundComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        TabComponent,            
        FocusDirective,
        SearchPipe,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [{
        provide: AuthServiceConfig, useFactory: provideConfig
    },
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I have no clue where it is breaking, it is working like charm in local. But when I deploy in the production I am facing this issue.

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing square bracket in the `providers` section of this code. I don't know if that is a copy/paste issue, or if adding that would fix the issue.

Comment: Richards that is not a problem. While posting I missed it.

Comment: Okay. Anyway you could add the full error message to the post if there is anything beyond what you have in the title? Is there a stack trace with more information?

Comment: @Madhankumar how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I have resolved this by deleting my dist directory and then I re runned the production build.

Answer (score 0):

your LOCAL code is good and deployment should work correctly.
I suppose that you deployed a different version of 'app.module.ts'.

The error you mentioned in the title was reproduced:

> 'Unexpected value 'Validators' imported by the module 'AppModule'.
>   Please add a @NgModule annotation' error.

- If you **comment** Option 1 from the following code;
- And **uncomment** Option 2 then the code starts working.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatIconModule
} from '@angular/material';
import {
  FormsModule, 
  //ReactiveFormsModule, // Option 2: it works
  Validators // <-- Option 1: here is what triggers an error
}    from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    //ReactiveFormsModule, // Option 2: it works
    Validators // <-- Option 1: here is what triggers an error
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And two more files to make validation example complete.
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- Validators should be here

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ]);
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl">
        <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
        Please enter a valid email address
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
        Email is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```